# replace "and" with shift and rotate registers with the result and input staying the same

Tags: assembly, mips, mips64

```
.text       
.globl __start 

__start:            
li $t1,9        
li $t2,7        
        
addi $t1,$t1,3

addi $t2,$t2,3

li $t3,0xFFFFFFFF    
srl $t3,$t3,$t1    
sll $t3,$t3,$t1    
sll $t3,$t3,$t2   
srl $t3,$t3,$t2    
not $t3,$t3
    
li $s1,0x12345678   # input data in $s1 register

and $s2,$s1,$t3     # output data in $s2 register

li $v0,10      
syscall         # exit
```

Comment: I don't see any question.

Comment: how do you replace the and registers with rotates or shifts?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that sequence ending with `not $t3,$t3` creates an AND mask with 1 bits at the edges but zeros in the middle.  So you could do the same thing of knocking out the middle bits by rotating then to one end, shifting them out, and then rotating back.

---

But MIPS doesn't have hardware rotate instructions.  `ror` and `rol` are only pseudo-instructions that shift twice and OR, so this would not be more efficient.

Creating and using an AND mask probably *is* the best way to zero a range of bits between two inputs.  But you can probably construct the mask more efficiently.  Like `~((1<<high) - (1<<low))` or something like that, which takes one `li reg,1`, two `sllv`, one `subu`, and one `not`.  There might be an off-by-one in that expression; I didn't check since this isn't what you were really asking about.

Or of course if the bit positions are known constants, you should just do the math at assemble time and run one `li` with the mask.  (1 or 2 hardware instructions, or even just an `andi` if the resulting mask has set bits only in the low 16.)  A good assembler will let you write expressions involving constants and evaluate it, like `li $t1, ~((1<<9) - (1<<7))`.  But MARS for example doesn't let you do that.  You'd have to hard-code the `0xfffffe7f`